# get url redirected

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect

I wanna get the url that has been redirected, for example, if I'm trying to open my wishlist and it redirect me to login page, I wanna get the wishlist url.

I want the link that I type in the browser, that is redirected.

Magento 1.9

Comment: For which version of magento

Comment: Let me know what exat possition or where u would like open u wishlist so that I can guide u

Comment: what I want is, enable the posibility to do this: add product to wishlist -> login is prompted -> when I've logged in I get redirected to wishlist in my account with the product added.  Rigth now i get redirected to wishlist but without the product added. I'm trying to send the wishlist url of the product as a url to return after login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can got it in the method "setRedirect" in the class `Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http` in Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php, then, I was cloned that class to do the modifications I need.